# Why I can no longer create *separate* Gmail Desktop apps?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, desktop, web-app

I used to have a few "Desktop Apps" for Gmail created as shortcuts, following these steps:

⠇(top right) > **More tools** > **Create Shortcut** > **Open as Window**

I'd then have one app per Gmail account. It worked perfectly. Now, it's no longer possible. If you create one Gmail app per account using the above steps, a **single** Desktop Gmail app is created, with the various accounts "nested" as windows. This is incredibly bad as you can't use the standard <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows and, more importantly, every time you close the app, you have to manually re-add ALL the accounts to that single Gmail app.

How can we go back to the previous behavior? Any workaround? I'm on Mac and tried to edit the `info.plist` files unsuccessfully.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/101395/510452

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem as well. I couldn't find anything that worked so instead I used another browser (I used Microsoft edge) to do the same thing instead of Chrome.
Follow this link
https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-gmail-on-your-desktop/

It'll run through how to do it with Microsoft edge.
I reckon as the other browser doesn't have multiple log ins the app doesn't automatically switch to the default account.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello, CreatorOfThe7X. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.